# Humming from Door Bell TRansformer

Tags: doorbell

Lately, I have been hearing a loud humming sound coming from the vicinity of transformer and door bell chime area. Is this normal for a transformer/chime combination that is 40 years old??

Comment: No, cab you confirm that it is in fact the transformer?  More likely doorbell him is the solenoid in the chime, and that problem 99% of the time is stuck button.

Comment: Also, check the transformer and chime solenoid to feel if they're hot to touch. A hot chime solenoid indicates a stuck button, as @Tyson states; a hot transformer but cold solenoid means transformer may have a shorted turn and is failing.